# Java - processing a text file to identify each string delimited by a whitespace or a symbol

Tags: java, regex

Title may not be clear, but what I am trying to do is:

For a sample line of a text file (that may be a program):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

I want to build an array of every string as well as each symbol used. In this line case I want:

```
ArrayList x = ["public", "static", "void", "main", "(", "String","[","]","args",")","{"]
```

My first thought was to:

1. Split the string on whitespaces and all symbols to get all the strings with characters.
2. Add these to arraylist
3. Split the original line on characters or something to get the symbols
4. Add to arraylist

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I can't really see a clear solution.

Comment: Though not sure, it seems that you're trying to lexical analysis. In that case, JFlex would be helpful.

Comment: @cs2016 does it have to be in the same order as in the input line?

Comment: I am trying to mimic the steps of lexical analysis, thanks I'll look into that

Comment: @MichalSchielmann the arraylist can be in any order

Answer (score 2):

You can split your text using a regex like this:

```
(?=[\s\W])|(?<=[\s\W])
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fU3iU7/2)**

You will have your text splitted as below:

[image]

Your code would be:

```
public void testSplit()
{
    String str = "public static void main(String[] args){";
    String[] arr = str.split("(?=[\\s\\W])|(?<=[\\s\\W])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
// Print: 
// [public,  , static,  , void,  , main, (, String, [, ],  , args, ), {, ]
```

Then you can clean the empty string from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant it does what you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String inputString = "public static void main(String[] args){";
    String charsToFind = "\\[\\]\\{\\}\\(\\)";
    String[] outputArray = (inputString.replaceAll("[^"+charsToFind+"]", "").replaceAll("(?!^)"," ") + inputString.replaceAll("[" + charsToFind + "]", " ")).replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));
}
```

So here, first we have to define the chars that you want to use as delimiters (that is `charsToFind` variable).
Then what the code does is:

1. It replaces everything but the defined chars and inserts a space between every two chars.

   `inputString.replaceAll("[^"+charsToFind+"]", "").replaceAll("(?!^)"," ")`
2. This way you have only your special characters separated by `space`.
3. Next it substitutes all special characters for spaces and adds the result to the previous one

   `+ inputString.replaceAll("[" + charsToFind + "]", " ")`
4. And at the end it removes additional spaces and `split`s everything by space to an `String[]` array:

   `.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split(" ");`

Output:

```
[(, [, ], ), {, public, static, void, main, String, args]
```

The answer by Fede is more elegant but after creating the array you need to remove empty entries. I hope this solution would help.